# How to fix Unsupported class file major version 57 in maven for Java 13 and Spring

Tags: java, maven, build, compiler-errors

I have this error

How to fix it?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 57
```

I have such POM

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>13</java.version>
</properties>
```

Project has many literals, so Java 13 is required.

Comment: Most likely, Spring doesn't support Java 13 yet. Try adding `-target 12` to your javac command line or to your pom.xml: `<properties> <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>`

Comment: I think Spring 2.2 is required, but how to add it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Changing Spring boot version in the pom.xml solved this issue for me.

```
   <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
```

Answer (score 3):

The 2.2.0 version of spring-boot hasn't been released yet, but there is a milestone build (M4). If you want to use it, you need to add another maven repository to your pom.xml file:

```
<repositories>
    <repository> 
        <id>repository.spring.milestone</id> 
        <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name> 
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url> 
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

You can then depend on the milestone build:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.M4</version>
</parent>
```

See also: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-maven-repository

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally upgraded my java before doing the:

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 6.2.2 --debug --stacktrace
```

This is the only surefire way I was able to upgrade to jdk13 and gradle 6.2.2. There might be a simpler less destructive way but this worked for me

---

To fix this I installed the latest gradle

```
brew install gradle
```

From root of project, move the existing build and settings to temp location

```
mv build.gradle build.gradle.old
mv settings.gradle settings.gradle.old
```

re init the gradle application and follow prompts

```
gradle init
```

move the build and settings back

```
mv build.gradle.old build.gradle
mv settings.gradle.old settings.gradle
```

rebuild your project

Answer (score 0):

The posted answers didn't work for me. Following did:

I know my spring boot project is supposed to be run with JAVA 11. But on my new laptop it didn't run anymore with the same error warning about file major version 57.

1. I checked that the HOME_PATH is directing to JAVA 11 by running `JAVA -version`in the windows console. It only showed Java 11, so that was ok.
2. check the [image: project structure -> SDKs] -> here I had another SDK (Azul 13) in the list. I deleted it -> an error puped up after building the project again to check the JVM
3. The Gradle JVM was still pointing to 'azul 13' -> changed it to JAVA_HOME

[image]

Then it worked.